Binomial coefficient with stix2
I noticed that binomial coefficients are poorly rendered using stix2.
Especially in inline math mode, the bottom symbol seems too low, half way outside of the parenthesis.
Is it the intentional design from stix2 ?
Is it a bug ? Any workaround ?
MWE, running on TexLive full 2024.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
Binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ $\binom{N}{K}$ 
$$\binom{n}{k} \binom{N}{K}$$ 
\end{document}



Hmm the minimum size of delimiters in textstyle extended fractions is fontdimen21 which is set at 10pt but seems too small here
See What do different \fontdimen<num> mean

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$x$}% force math setup
%\showthe\fontdimen21 \textfont2
\fontdimen21 \textfont2=14pt

Binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ $\binom{N}{K}$ 
\[\binom{n}{k} \binom{N}{K}\]
\end{document}


Thank you for very fast reply !
\sbox0{$x$}% force math setup
%\showthe\fontdimen21 \textfont2
\fontdimen21 \textfont2=14pt
Are these some lines from stix2.sty file ?
Can I just print them in a preambule of my multifile project? (outside of \begin{document} \end{document})

you can put it all in \AtBeginDocument{..} in the preamble @Mc_PanBagnat

@Mc_PanBagnat the lines are not from the package, I just set it to 14 "by eye" just now for your question

Thank you very much !
It works well in the MWE. But I cannot make it work in my big multi-file project...
Perhaps is it more involved and there is a conflict with another imported package.

@Mc_PanBagnat try to isolate a smaller example and feel free to ask a new question you can reference this one.
